# Finding direction cosines.

Tags: trigonometry, analytic-geometry

Determine the direction cosines of a diagonal of the parallelepiped,the length of whose sides are in the ratio $2:3:4$ .

i know the definition of direction cosines. But i do not know the approach to solve this problem.

Comment: you can use Google to seach for direction cosinus

Comment: i did. But i can not solve this problem.

Comment: The answer ought to be $(2/\sqrt{29},3/\sqrt{29},4/\sqrt{29})$